# alphanumeric string in OData v4's function string parameter is parsed as int into string, or null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I'm having some problems passing an alphanumeric string as a parameter for an OData function. Here is its signature:

```
[EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult GetForConstant([FromODataUri]string constant)
```

and its configuration:

```
var getForConstant = collection.Function("GetForConstant")
    .ReturnsFromEntitySet<BasicParameter>("Parameters");
getForConstant.Parameter<string>("constant");
```

and its metadata:

```
<Function Name="GetForConstant" IsBound="true">
    <Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Collection(MyApp.BasicParameter)" />
    <Parameter Name="constant" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="false" />
    <ReturnType Type="MyApp.BasicParameter" />
</Function>
```

Here are different parsed values of the "constant" controller method parameter with the associated call:

```
http://xxx/api/Parameters/Default.GetForConstant(constant='123')
constant: "123"

http://xxx/api/Parameters/Default.GetForConstant(constant='999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999')
constant: "1E+48"

http://xxx/api/Parameters/Default.GetForConstant(constant='12aa') 
constant: "12" 

http://xxx/api/Parameters/Default.GetForConstant(constant='aa')
constant: null 

http://xxx/api/Parameters/Default.GetForConstant(constant='aa12') 
constant: null
```

If I try without the single quotes, I get a 406 Not Acceptable error.

I tried updating WebAPI 2.2 for OData to the latest version (5.4.0) and also updated to the latest ODataLib (6.10.0) but that didn't help.

Any idea what's wrong?

If it matters, I'm mixing WebAPI and MVC (for help pages). Here are my routing configurations.

MVC:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute( //MapRoute for controllers inheriting from standard Controller
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

WebAPI:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( //MapHTTPRoute for controllers inheriting ApiController
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

OData:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder() { Namespace = "Default" };

*snip! model configurations here*

        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "api", model);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the $metadata for the function?

Comment: @Brad i've added the metadata to the question.

Comment: Everything looks ok from what you've shown, although obviously for some reason your string appears to be parsed as a number before being provided to your method. Are you using any custom routing conventions, model binders, or anything like that?

Comment: Besides somewhat mixing MVC and WebAPI, everything is as basic as it can get. I've added the routing configurations to the question.

Comment: Hmm, the overlap between WebApi and OData is interesting - I assume OData is registered first? The fact that your function is being called seems to suggest that's ok. Something you could use to as a debug to is to throw a ODataRoute attribute on your function [ODataRoute("/Parameters/Default.GetForConstants(constant={constant})"] and see if that helps. If it does, it definitely suggests a routing issue.

Comment: I'll try that for sure soon. Meanwhile, here's a blog post I did on mixing mvc and webapi. It may contain some helpful details I didn't think related to my issue here: http://jerther.blogspot.ca/2014/11/aspnet-web-api-2-help-pages-odata_28.html

Comment: Adding the attribute works. So you say that would mean a routing issue. Any idea where to look at? Or do I really have to set this attribute to all my functions?

Comment: It gets a little awkward from this point on. The MapODataServiceRoute overload you're using internally calls ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting, which internally adds a number of conventions. It should be using FunctionRoutingConvention for this, but it's implementation should be fine with strings. Maybe you can try and see what convention was actually used, but that would probably require debugging using the source from github (https://github.com/OData/WebApi)

Comment: Outch. In that case, I'm better off with just adding the attribute for now. I don't have many functions with string parameters so I can do with that. You can make this into a solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment chain on the question, it seems like the manner in which the routing conventions are populating the function parameters is doing something strange. Since attribute based routing is the first that runs, using it seems to make sure "the right thing" happens.

To narrow down the issue further will require debugging into the routing conventions to find which is executing for this scenario, and what it's doing to populate the route data.

So meanwhile, adding the following attribute to the function works:

```
[ODataRoute("/Parameters/Default.GetForConstant(constant={constant})"]
```

Comment: I don't have ODataRouteAttribute, so this doesn't work.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Apparently issue 223 was resolved with [build 5.5](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#07-04-5-5), what build of OData WebApi are you using?